# IPython Notebook Crash

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I installed Windows 64-bit Anaconda latest distribution, and the when I started an IPython notebook, I can't evaluate any expression inside the notebook, and in the console this appears as I create a new notebook or try to evaluate a cell.

```
http://pastebin.com/WBAuCspM
```

I don't really know what's wrong.

Comment: Looks like yet another unicode bug on Windows + Python 2. Do you have time to try to reproduce it with IPython master?

Comment: This should be fixed in IPython master as of [#4336](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4336)